# session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 65.0.3325.0

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

We have a jenkins job on which we are running some tests using chrome and java.
Our slave is an archlinux and we installed a package `chromium` to make it possible to run chrome headless and make chromedriver available.

```
println "chromedriver -v".execute().text
ChromeDriver 2.33 (0)
println "chromium -version".execute().text
Chromium 64.0.3282.119
```

This worked fine for a few days till yesterday we suddenly got this error:

```
<<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 65.0.3325.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551591 (bcc4a2cdef0f6b942b2bb8049068f65340fa2a69),platform=Linux 4.9.78-1-lts x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

We did not change the code and we didn't update any tool on our slaves.
How is this possible. Our java code does not contain some remote dependency which could require an updated version.

What is the reason that the Chrome version must be updated while nothing changed?

Answer (score 2):

We were using selenide too which seems to download its own drivers, explained on their [github](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/wiki/How-Selenide-creates-WebDriver).

This fixed it to force selenide to use our existing chromedriver:

```
mvn clean install -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the chrome browser to the latest version, i use this commands in a yml file for eg. circleci in my project.

```
- run: sudo apt-get install libappindicator3-1
- run: curl -L -o google-chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
- run: sudo sed -i 's|HERE/chrome\"|HERE/chrome\" --disable-setuid-sandbox|g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
- run: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome.deb
- run: rm google-chrome.deb
```